# Bootstrap accordion jumps to center of the page on load

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a side navigation panel using Bootstrap collapse and want all sections to be open on load.  My code below does this, but it also jumps to the middle of the page on load.  It looks like the page jumps right under the second expandable section.  Is there a way to fix this?

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">My Case<i class="pull-right fa fa-plus"></i></a></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse show" id="collapseOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">At A Glance</a> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Authorized Representatives</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Benefits</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Granite Advantage</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Documents</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Notices</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">My Profile<i class="pull-right fa fa-plus"></i></a></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse show" id="collapseTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Contact Information</a> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Get In Touch</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Security Settings</a>           
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Need Help?</h4>
      <p class="small m-t-sm">If you have a question about your case, contact the Customer Service Center.</p>
      <br/>
      <i class="fas fa-phone fa-flip-horizontal m-r-sm blue"></i>1-844-CALL-HELP
      <br/>
      <i class="fas fa-envelope m-r-sm blue"></i><a href="#" target="_blank">Email</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete "show" from class names. And add this script to the head section.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#accordion .panel-collapse').collapse('toggle');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks!  I tried this and it does keep the panels open, but it still jumps to the second panel on load.  not sure what's is making this happen in the code...

Comment: when I checked on jsfiddle everything seems like normal. Check your scripts on page. https://jsfiddle.net/emrahguclu/repz7owd/1/